# Silex/Twig : Conflict between a custom filter and form widget

Tags: php, twig, silex

I think I found a bug in Silex Twig Provider.
I tried to add a custom filter in Twig (the code is from the documentation) :

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('rot13', function ($string) {
  return str_rot13($string);
});

$app['twig']->addFilter($filter);
```

The problem is when I add this filter and I try to use form_widget like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

An exception is raised :

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The filter "trans" does not exist in
>   "form_div_layout.html.twig" at line 75

I tried solutions found on Internet like :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'translator.messages' => array(),
));
```

But It doesn't work, maybe because I use the Translation Provider to translate error messages...

Anyway, add a filter shouldn't cause this kind of behaviour...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Silex documentation show the following code](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html) as example:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
  $twig->addGlobal('pi', 3.14);
  $twig->addFilter('levenshtein', new \Twig_Filter_Function('levenshtein'));
  return $twig;
}));
```

I think you should try to add the filter in this way.

Comment: Your solution is better than mine. It fixes another problem. Thank you Ralf.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : The addFilter must be add after the TranslationServerProvider registering.

In the order I've:

1. FormServiceProvider
2. TwigServiceProvider
3. TranslationServiceProvider
4. addFilter